# Drupal 7 Forum - Allow Users to 'hide' their online status

Tags: views, nodes

I am desperately trying to find a way for my users to 'hide' their online status from other users. Currently all users online are displayed in the drupal 'who's online' box.

Ideally I would look for a way to create a custom checkbox field (online_status) and then find a way for the who's online block to check that.

Any ideas, modules or approaches anyone can recommend.
My current thinking is to do it via Views and a custom block

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_block_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) to alter the content that is returned by who's online block. Ideally use the same logic that was implemented in user.module user_block_view function, delta **who's online** block but with extra validations.

Add a field called Show online status to User Profile. Let's say yes or no.

Read the above field value in the alter function for all users online and filter them before displaying.

Hope it solves !